# Save excel file as unicode text vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file with multiple rows and columns I want a VBA script that can save the excel file as unicode and keep the formatting that the excel file is in.
is this possible?

many thanks

Comment: A text file has no formatting.  You might need to explain your needs in more detail.

Comment: simply cus  the possible billions kinds of different formatting, you would need to do it on your own... each cell has font (size color type...) backround (type, color[s]...) borders (each border with type, thickness, color...) and also conditional formatting... doing this as plain text would be ~2-20kb just to cover everything for each cell (and you would need to do it manually)

Comment: I would like to clear format of the excel, simple text file and have tab spacing between each row and column, or simply the exact file you would get when you go file -> save as -> Unicode Text, hope that's clear

Comment: If that's all you need then use the macro recorder and start with the code it produces.